# SharePoint state machine wf

Tags: workflow

I have a problem. I have three things in project: content type, state machine wf and a list. At now, my workflow associate whith list on web, but I need associate this workflow with  my list from project. I can find my WF in list via WorkflowAssociations and associate with enother list but what can I do if workflow not associate with any list on my web, how can I find it? Can I get or set SPWorkflowAssociation directly from workflow?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to Associate a workflow following below URL:
[SHAREPOINT ASSOCIATING A WORKFLOW TO A LIST](http://blogit.create.pt/blogs/marcosilva/archive/2007/12/10/SharePoint-Associating-a-Workflow-to-a-list.aspx)

The key is to get `SPWorkflowTemplate` and than create `SPWorkflowAssociation`, something like:

```
SPWorkflowTemplate wflTemplate = spWeb.WorkflowTemplates.GetTemplateByName("NameOfWorkflowTemplate", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);

SPList wflTaskList = spWeb.Lists["Tasks"];

SPList wflHistoryList = spWeb.Lists["Workflow History"];

SPWorkflowAssociation wflAss = SPWorkflowAssociation.CreateListAssociation(wflTemplate, "NameOfTheWorkflow", wflTaskList, wflHistoryList);
```

PS: Looks duplicate to [Add workflow to a list programmatically](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/4714/add-workflow-to-a-list-programmatically)

Comment: Thanks, but where I can get workflowTemplateName for my own workflow. At now I get in from SPWorkflowAssociation instance.

Comment: In Elements.xml you have Name property for Workflow.. Try using that !